# Android : GCMIntentReceiver make a notification unless an activity is running

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

So in my application, the user is on some kind of a wait screen and the server may push him result in a few second or in a few minutes.

So I would like the GCMIntentReceiver to check if an activity is running. If it is, I would like to start an other activity. If it's not, it should make a Notification.

But I don't know how to do that ^^

Answer (score 1):

Step #1: Have your activity implement a `BroadcastReceiver` for some custom action string, registered with a high-priority `IntentFilter`, where you update your UI and call `abortBroadcast()`.

Step #2: Have another `BroadcastReceiver`, in the manifest, for the same custom action string, where you raise the `Notification`.

Step #3: Send that broadcast from your `GCMIntentReceiver`.

Comment: If I don't want the notification to be shown when the activity is runnning, I need to use a Service using a similar BroadcastReceiver. Am I right ?

Comment: @Dam: No. You follow the instructions that I wrote above. Here is a blog post with additional details: http://commonsware.com/blog/2010/08/11/activity-notification-ordered-broadcast.html